# SET ROLES does not work as expected

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, roles

I have a problem. `SET ROLE` does not work as I expected. I have code sample:

```
DECLARE 
  ln_ln NUMBER;
  ln_1 NUMBER;
BEGIN
  ln_ln := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
  DBMS_SQL.PARSE(ln_ln, 'SET ROLE SOME_ROLE IDENTIFIED BY SOME_PASSWORD',DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
  ln_1 := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(ln_ln);
  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(ln_ln);
  ln_ln := SOME_PACKAGE.SOME_FUNCTION;
END;
```

The `SOME_ROLE` have grant to `SOME_PACKAGE`. When I run this block, I get error that package does not exists. When I run this everything is fine:

```
DECLARE
  ln_ln NUMBER;
  ln_1 NUMBER;
BEGIN
  ln_ln := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
  DBMS_SQL.PARSE(ln_ln, 'SET ROLE SOME_ROLE IDENTIFIED BY SOME_PASSWORD',DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
  ln_1 := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(ln_ln);
  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(ln_ln);
END;
/
DECLARE
  ln_ln NUMBER;
BEGIN
  ln_ln := SOME_PACKAGE.SOME_FUNCTION;
END;
```

When I run this, everything is good too:

```
DECLARE
  ln_ln NUMBER;
BEGIN
  ln_ln := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
  DBMS_SQL.PARSE(ln_ln, 'SET ROLE SOME_ROLE IDENTIFIED BY SOME_PASSWORD',DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
  ln_1 := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(ln_ln);
  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(ln_ln);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :x := SOME_PACKAGE.SOME_FUNCTION; END;' USING OUT ln_ln;
END;
```

I tried `EXECUTE IMMDIATE`, `DBMS_SESSION.SET_ROLE` and `DBMS_UTILITY.exec_ddl_statement` instead of `DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE`. Can anyone tell me some workaround or explain why this stuff keeps happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I undertand you have no permissions to access SOME_PACKAGE before you run SET ROLE .
In this case, your first script will never work, because pl/sql is not a scripting language,
it compiles code before running it. When parser reaches SOME_PACKAGE it fails because your user doesn't know what that string is.

You already have a solutions:

1. make 2 anonimous blocks

   - grant permissions
   - execute function (this block is compiled only after first block is executed)
2. use dynamic sql like EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (code comiled at runtime)

Comment: But is there any way to re-parse anonymous block after set roles? I want to make first option to work, because then I don't have to remake more then 900 components :)

Comment: the only option is to set role before the execution. if this block is part of application that you do not control, you may use onlogon trigger to set proper permissions. Another thing... if all 900 components look alike, you may write a converter to the "execute immediate" solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I decided to make a script which separates one anonimus block in to two.